# SciFi Series about a single alien and space-travel portals

Tags: story-identification

I’m trying to remember the series (three or four books) I read a while ago (5+ years).

Details:

- Science Fiction
- Human future, multiple planets
- Hardish SciFi
- There’s one alien “species” that is entirely a single alien that controls multiple other aliens that have been trapped on a single world.
- There are portals that can travel between worlds that end up releasing them and causing a war.
- There’s also a crashed alien spaceship that has a hidden alien on it.
- The alien on the spaceship is controlling a group of humans.

Answer (score 11):

I found it (after a lot of scrolling).

It's [Pandora's Star](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/45252.Pandora_s_Star) by Peter F. Hamilton.

Comment: Well done for finding what you were looking for! Please don't forget to accept your self-answer in 48 hours